# complex grouping using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is something that i am working on and i am unable to find answers on how to do it. My table looks like this:

```
id | Status | Assigned | workflow_Id | Date     |
------------------------------------------------
1  |Open    | John     | 123       |12-02-2018
------------------------------------------------
2  |Resp    | John     | 123       |13-02-2018
------------------------------------------------
3  |Open    | John     | 123       |14-02-2018
------------------------------------------------
4  |Resp    | John     | 123       |16-02-2018
------------------------------------------------
```

Workflow id is the unique key. There will be multiple ids assigned to one workflow. So here John opens the workflow and responds to it. Again, there might be something else that he opens and responds. I am trying to calculate the average handle time for each response. My end data should look something like this:

```
Assigned |Workflow_id | Open Date  | Resp Date  | Avg_Handle_Duration |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
john     | 123        | 12-02-2018 | 13-02-2018 | 1 day  |
john     | 123        | 14-02-2018 | 16-02-2018 | 2 days |
```

EDIT: I am using Postgres. Sorry for missing out this detail.

Comment: please specify which sql version you are using.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are stuck?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Can the open/resp be nested?  What if there are not the same number of each?

Comment: Gordon - ideally there should be one responded to each open. there might be extra responses but i will calculate only for the first response.

Answer (score 0):

You want *conditional* aggregation :

```
select *, datediff(day, OpenDate, RespDate) as Avg_Handle_Duration
from (select Assigned, workflow_Id,
            max(case when Status  = 'Open' then Date end) as OpenDate,
            max(case when Status  = 'Resp' then Date end) as RespDate,
      from table t
      group by Assigned, workflow_Id; 
    ) t;
```

Use *DBMS* specific date function (i.e. date difference) i have used `SQL Server` specific since o/p has no DBMS tagged. So, use accordingly.

Very BAD for me cause i misread the question. Well, if your *DBMS* has analytical function then you can use it as difference of them.

```
select assigned, workflow_id, 
       max(case when Status = 'Open' then date end) as OpenDate,
       max(case when Status = 'Resp' then date end) as RespDate,
       . . .  
from (select *,
             1+(row_number() over (order by date)-1)/2 Seq
      from table
     ) t
group by assigned, workflow_id, Seq;
```

Comment: OP wants two rows for John, 123. Your query will only return one row.

Comment: @jarlh... You are right i just misread the question. Btw thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQL Server Solution (no DBMS is specified) using correlated subqueries.

Other DBMS products will have a different `DATEDIFF` syntax

```
SELECT  a.Assigned,
        a.workflow_Id,
        a.Date AS OpenDate,
        (SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM Workflow WHERE Date > a.Date AND Status = 'Resp' ORDER BY Date) AS RespDate,
        DATEDIFF(day,a.Date,(SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM Workflow WHERE Date > a.Date AND Status = 'Resp' AND Assigned = a.Assigned AND workflow_Id = a.workflow_Id ORDER BY Date)) AS Avg_Handle_Duration 
FROM    Workflow a
WHERE   Status = 'Open'
```

**EDIT** - You've now stated its Postgres so try the below

```
SELECT  a.Assigned,
        a.workflow_Id,
        a.Date AS OpenDate,
        (SELECT  Date FROM Workflow WHERE Date > a.Date AND Status = 'Resp' ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1) AS RespDate,
        DATE_PART('day',(SELECT Date FROM Workflow WHERE Date > a.Date AND Status = 'Resp' AND Assigned = a.Assigned AND workflow_Id = a.workflow_Id ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1)::date) -DATE_PART('day',a.Date::date) AS Avg_Handle_Duration 
FROM    Workflow a
WHERE   Status = 'Open'
```

Comment: Any idea on how to use TOP 1 for postgres. I am using Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Have a correlated sub-query to find each Open's following Resp. Do it all in a defived table to simply duration calculation:

```
select dt.Assigned, dt.Workflow_id, dt.OpenDate,
       dt.RespDate, dt.RespDate- dt.OpenDate as Avg_Handle_Duration 
from
(select t1.Assigned, t1.Workflow_id, t1.date as OpenDate,
        (select min(t2.date) from tablename t2
         where t2.Status = 'Resp'
           and t2.date > t1.date
           and t1.assigned = t2.assigned
           and t1.Workflow_id = t2.Workflow_id) as RespDate
 from tablename t1
 where t1.Status = 'Open') dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional aggregation, but the problem is that you don't have a second key for it.  One method is to use this key using `row_number()` and arithmetic:

```
select assigned, workflow_id, 
       max(case when Status = 'Open' then date end) as OpenDate,
       max(case when Status = 'Resp' then date end) as RespDate,
       < however your database manages date differences 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by assigned, workflow_id, floor( (seqnum - 1) / 2);
```

That said, this assumes that the open/resp records are strictly interlaced.  If that is not true, then you should ask another question with more explanation, a proper database tag, and better sample data.